# AngularJS smart Table Global search only on displayed field

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle, smart-table

I'm using smartTable and I love it, it is really nice. I have an issue with the global search, to perform global search with smart table, you just have to define an input like this:

```
<input st-search class="form-control" placeholder="Global search ..." type="text"/>
```

The problem is that this will search on all the data returned by the server.

I would like to find a way to search only in the displayed data, so if the data returned by the server is not displayed, I don't want that the search finds it.

I created this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tonio31/n4Lyf09n/) that shows the problem, in there we display the firstName and lastName but not the "id"
If you search for a number, for instance "12", the result display will be "Laurent Renard" because his ID is "12".

So the the question is : 
**Is there a way to globally search only on the displayed data withtout using a custom filter ?**